# I'm just a Simple Newbie

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-clues

After figuring out each clue, you should also figure out why the clues are grouped the way they are. All answers are in English.

**Group 1**

1. She changed after French novel (5)
2. A hot underworld hiding everywhere (6,3,5)
3. Upset cheaters?! (8)
4. "Eh, ahoy!" - new exclamation? (2,4)
5. Existing within extra livelihood (5)

**Group 2**

1. I added tempo again (3,4,4)
2. Many back in core aid assembly become streamlined (11)
3. Online dating correct to lead vigil? (7,4)
4. Strong good guys, according to champion in petitions (11)
5. Type of tea after tea - sounds overly lengthy (3,4)

**Group 3**

1. All in all, mortal! (5,5,3)
2. Motor might first heat engine (5,7)
3. Breathe! Warn his crazy one who purifies thinking? (3, 11)
4. Sadly got no cliche relating to technology (11)
5. Feeling nothing in no time? Weird (7)

**Group 4**

1. Introduction complete; break out back. No pressure! (8)
2. Protection club stores weapons? (6)
3. Finish melting nail in iron (6)
4. Copy or twin? (6)
5. Views Republican fellow in polls (11)

**Group 5**

1. Inside among elected (6)
2. Handle car before exclamation (5)
3. Come out on top and win well (3,5)
4. Mama pig died identifying computer part (11)
5. Guarantee missing right approach (7)

**Bonus!**
Womanizer: young man going after celebrity (7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group 1

> She changed after French novel (5)

> FRESH (SHE* after FR)

> A hot underworld hiding everywhere (6,3,5)

> AROUND THE WORLD ((A HOT UNDERWORLD)* though there's no anagram indicator)

> Upset cheaters?! (7)

> TEACHERS (CHEATERS* though there doesn't really seem to be a def, and this is (8) not (7))

> "Eh, ahoy!" - new exclamation? (2,4)

> OH YEAH (EH AHOY*)

> Existing within extra livelihood (5)

> ALIVE (substring)

These are all

> tracks from Daft Punk's first album, "Homework".

Group 2

> I added tempo again (3,4,4)

> ONE MORE TIME (I=one, added=more, tempo=time)

> Many back in core aid assembly become streamlined (11)

> AERODYNAMIC (MANY< in (CORE AID)*)

> Online dating correct to lead vigil? (7,4)

> DIGITAL LOVE ((TO LEAD VIGIL)*)

> Strong good guys, according to champion in petitions (11)

> SUPERHEROES (PER HERO in SUES)

> Type of tea after tea - sounds overly lengthy (3,4)

> TOO LONG (OOLONG after T)

These are all

> tracks from Daft Punk's second album, "Discovery".

Group 3

> All in all, mortal! (5,5,3)

> HUMAN AFTER ALL (this seems just to be a definition)

> Motor might first heat engine (5,7)

> STEAM MACHINE (I guess this is just STEAM + MACHINE but the structure seems a bit loose)

> Breathe! Warn his crazy one who purifies thinking? (3, 11)

> THE BRAINWASHER ((BREATHE WARN HIS)*)

> Sadly got no cliche relating to technology (11)

> TECHNOLOGIC ((GOT NO CLICHE)*)

> Feeling nothing in no time? Weird (7)

> EMOTION (O in (NO TIME)*)

These are all

> tracks from Daft Punk's third album, "Human After All".

Group 4

> Introduction complete; break out back. No pressure! (8)

> OVERTURE (OVER + ERU(-p)T<)

> Protection club stores weapons? (6)

> ARMORY (ARMOR + Y)

> Finish melting nail in iron (6)

> FINALE (NAIL* in FE)

> Copy or twin? (6)

> CASTOR (CAST + OR)

> Views Republican fellow in polls (11)

> REFLECTIONS (R + F in ELECTIONS)

These are all

> tracks from Daft Punk's soundtrack for "Tron: Legacy".

Group 5

> Inside among elected (6)

> WITHIN (WITH + IN)

> Handle car before exclamation (5)

> TOUCH ([Ford Model] T before OUCH)

> Come out on top and win well (3,5)

> GET LUCKY (GET + LUCKY)

> Mama pig died identifying computer part (11)

> MOTHERBOARD (MOTHER + BOAR + D)

> Guarantee missing right approach (7)

> CONTACT (CONTRACT missing R)

These are all

> tracks from Daft Punk's fourth album, "Random Access Memories".

Bonus! Womanizer: young man going after celebrity (7)

> STARBOY (BOY after STAR)

Comment: Oof, today it was your turn to ninja me - was just finishing writing up Group 5! Well played Gareth +1 :)

Comment: Nailed it! I used this website (https://bestforpuzzles.com/cryptic-crossword-dictionary/anagram-indicators.html) for 1.2, and typically an exclamation mark after a clue indicates rot13(na "&yvg" pyhr jurer gur ragver pyhr vf gur qrsvavgvba naq gur jbeqcynl; "hcfrg purngref" zrnaf gb nantenz "purngref", ohg grnpuref nyfb "hcfrg (gujneg) purngref" - gur qrs vf na rknzcyr, urapr gur dhrfgvba znex). You're right about the number error though - I'll fix that

Comment: Not much convinced by "hiding" as an anagrind. These lists tend to err on the side of including anything that anyone could possibly think is an anagram indicator :-). I did understand that 1.3 was an &lit and meant to be a def-by-example but I still think it's too loose. Maybe "They upset cheaters?!" would be better, though then the _wordplay_ would be a bit loose instead :-).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yeah that's fair - I went into this knowing that some of these were going to be a bit of a stretch eg. rot13(gur uhzna nsgre nyy nyohz jnf fyvz cvpxvatf), but that the theme would help fill in some of these gaps, although that's not reallythe best approach for a puzzle; I'm still trying to figure out how to walk that line. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: You're welcome. Another bit of feedback: I found this a bit of a slog. That is: after solving a few from Group 1 and googling, it was clear what the theme was likely to be; after solving the rest of Group 1 and a couple from Group 2, this was confirmed, and then the rest of the solve was basically going through and matching things up. (Groups 4 and 5 could have been either way around, but solving one from either clears that up.) It felt like it might have been a better puzzle with fewer groups.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Also fair - I wasn't sure how obvious the theme was gonna be, and I wanted to take the same amount of rot13(fbatf sebz rnpu bs Qnsg Chax'f nyohzf) and five seemed like a nice round number. I've seen cryptic crosswords on here with more than 26 clues, so I thought this would be an OK amount, without realizing that there usually isn't that tight of an adherence to a theme in other puzzles, and that the crossword itself adds some puzzling value to it that this didn't have. Duly noted!